# Installing QGIS with osgeo4w-setup.exe gives unreadable Cyrillic text

Tags: qgis, installation, osgeo4w, encoding

When I try to install QGIS with osgeo4w-setup.exe, the Cyrillic text on one of the windows is unreadable.

I would like a screenshot of this text in English.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the English version of this installation step:

[image]